# Dynamic loaded XML and XmlTextReader character encoding issue

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I load a XML like this:

```
var url = Application.dataPath + @"/config.xml";
var www = new WWW(url);

while (!www.isDone)
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
}
```

After that I create a `XmlTextReader` in order to parse that XML:

```
GameSettings.ParseXML(new XmlTextReader(new StringReader(www.text)));
```

But I'm having problem with character encoding (é,ç,ã,ê, etc). What can I do make it works?

Comment: In the xml file, is the encoding specified in the header?

Comment: @KevinCook no!!! it was that!? :OO

Comment: @KevinCook well.. i put and still not working.. :(

Comment: maybe try Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(www.text)) and pass that to the stringreader?

Comment: What is the problem you're having with those characters? Keep in mind that Unity uses UTF-16, if you are having display problems.

Comment: @Bart If I save the file using `UTF8` it works. But the customer saved in `Western Windows 1252`. Now I can't convert that in anyway. Characters are displayed eaten like `você -> voc`

Comment: ... either have the customer save it with the proper encoding, or just open it in a text editor and do it yourself.

Comment: @Bart thats not a solution, in any time after some years someone can save it using wrong encoding.

Comment: Just have to specify to the customer that the file must be encoded in utf8 to work and leave it at that, if the encoding doesn't match the header, there is no way you are going to be able to "guess" what the encoding should be.

Comment: Then that's their problem. Make it a specific requirement. Don't complicate your life by having to support just anything that comes your way. That's going to be hell.

Comment: @Bart I though we could convert in a easy manner from characters encoding type.. why is that so difficult?

Comment: You can always follow Raymond Chen's advice: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/04/17/2158334.aspx still, if you aren't given the encoding, there is no way that you are going to get the encoding correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use [`WWW.text`](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/ScriptReference/WWW-text.html), the function expects the web page contents encoded in `UTF-8` or `ASCII` but your customer uses `Windows-1252`.

Like [Bart](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23655035/dynamic-loaded-xml-and-xmltextreader-character-encoding-issue/23665680#comment36335199_23655035) already suggested, the best way would be to request that the customer just uses UTF-8. If that is not possible und you are sure that the customer **always** uses `Windows-1252` you can convert the encoding inside your application.

```
Encoding windows1252 = Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1252");
Encoding utf8 = Encoding.UTF8;
byte[] windowsBytes = www.bytes;
byte[] utf8Bytes = Encoding.Convert(windows1252, utf8, windowsBytes);
string converted_xml = utf8.GetString(utf8Bytes);
```